# POSIX shell module frameworks

Tags: shell, sh

I have just happened across [shellfire](https://github.com/shellfire-dev/shellfire), Are there any other POSIX module frameworks in use at the moment?

Comment: A comment, `shellfire` is somewhat monolithic, could do with namespaces even if only vendor (e.g., along the lines of PHP [composer](https://packagist.org/) -- `nodejs` `npm` [name dispute resolution](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/disputes) page being the case in point here).

Comment: And despite the author's claims, shellfire isn't posix shell compatible.  It needs a shell that support local variables.

Comment: `typeset` is aliased by the looks (which at a cursory glance at the bourne shell man page is POSIX)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few `bash` module systems, see this [Ubuntu forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282713/is-there-a-package-management-system-for-shell-scripts).

By way of a suggested scheme for hand coded modules, placing modules with some sort of subroutine suffix (`_subr`, `.sub`, etc.) in a vendor subdir. of `lib` [edit: on reflection perhaps `libdata`], reading system directories in with a relative path:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e  # exit on error

# boilerplate
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
. ../share/vendor/install_dir.conf

# includes
. "$LIB_DIR"/vendor/shared_subr

# code...
```

'install_dir.conf':

```
ETC_DIR=/etc
BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin
SBIN_DIR=/usr/local/sbin
LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/libexec
LIBDATA_DIR=/usr/local/libdata
```

'shared_subr':

```
test -n "$__SHARED_SUBR__" || {
__SHARED_SUBR__=1

vendor__sub_do_something() {
    typeset _local_var _another_local_var

    # code...

    return 0
}

}
```

There are a lot of good reasons to use `shellfire` though.